# why this index is not a good fit for query like this

Tags: sql, database, indexing

let say I have the following index in my database:

```sql
CREATE INDEX myindex on t2(emp_no, title);
```

and my query:

```sql
SELECT 
    t1.emp_no,
    t1.name,
FROM
    t1, t2
WHERE t1.emp_no = t2.emp_no and t2.title = 'some value';
```

I was advised to not use that index for the query, b/c it's useless and somehow it may make the query slower.
but why and how this index isn't useful?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and indexing usage is quite different between different DBMS products. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: Not performance related, but: you should really start using the "modern" (nearly 30 years old) explicit `JOIN` operator instead of the ancient and fragile implicit joins

Comment: You can't really "not use and index" - the query optimizer will decide if it makes sense to use the index or not. And more often than not the optimizer gets it right.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the table definitions. But if you are planning to filter on `title` as the first step of execution, putting that column to the front of the index would work better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should be written using **standard**, explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT t1.emp_no, t1.name,
FROM t1 JOIN
     t2
     ON t1.emp_no = t2.emp_no and t2.title = 'some value';
```

For this query, one optimal index is on `t2(emp_no, title)`.  This should be fine.  The execution plan will scan `t1` and essentially look up the matching values in `t2` using the index.

Because you only want columns from `t1`, `exists` would be a typically way to write the query:

```
SELECT t1.emp_no, t1.name,
FROM t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM t2
              WHERE t1.emp_no = t2.emp_no and t2.title = 'some value'
             );
```

This would use the same index.

Comment: Where does NOT EXISTS come from? The original query seems to ask for records that *do* exist.  And why is the index `(emp_no, title)` "optimal" when it does not allow to first find the (presumably few) matching rows in t2 that have the requested title and then pick the matching rows from t1 by emp_no (which might be a primary key there for all we know)?

Comment: @Thilo . . . That is a really good question.  I'm not sure but I fixed the answer.